# Using "encore" with "ne .. rien"

Tags: traduction, négation

> You haven't told me anything.

would be translated as

> Tu ne m'as rien dit.

So would

> You haven't told me anything **yet**.

be translated as

> Tu ne m'as rien dit **encore**.

? Can "encore" be used with "ne .. rien" in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word order is not *quite* correct:

> Tu ne m'as encore rien dit.

*Tu ne m'as rien dit encore.* would be "You didn't tell me anything again."